# c++ Segmentation fault when do list.push_back(), correct on the host, error on the arm

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, arm, cross-platform

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x400741e0 in std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*) ()
   from /mnt/yaffs2/Cdatabox/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x400741e0 in std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*) ()
   from /mnt/yaffs2/Cdatabox/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00012df8 in std::list<std::list<Cbox::SteadyNode, std::allocator<Cbox::SteadyNode> >, std::allocator<std::list<Cbox::SteadyNode, std::allocator<Cbox::SteadyNode> > > >::_M_insert (this=0xbe9d1af0, __position=..., __x=...)
    at /opt/arm-2008q3-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2/bits/stl_list.h:1342
#2  0x00012e30 in std::list<std::list<Cbox::SteadyNode, std::allocator<Cbox::SteadyNode> >, std::allocator<std::list<Cbox::SteadyNode, std::allocator<Cbox::SteadyNode> > > >::push_back (this=0xbe9d1af0, __x=...)
    at /opt/arm-2008q3-linux/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/../../../../arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2/bits/stl_list.h:876
#3  0x0000d508 in Cbox::SteadyAnalysis::__dealSteady (this=0xbe9d1a98)
    at ../include/class/SteadyAnalysis.h:237
#4  0x0000dc7c in Cbox::SteadyAnalysis::input (this=0xbe9d1a98,
    weight=1467031, rawTime=1552067705)
    at ../include/class/SteadyAnalysis.h:110
#5  0x0000deb4 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbe9d1d74) at SteadyAnalysis.cc:30
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function _ZNSt15_List_node_base4hookEPS_:
   0x400741d0 <+0>:     ldr     r3, [r1, #4]
   0x400741d4 <+4>:     stm     r0, {r1, r3}
   0x400741d8 <+8>:     ldr     r2, [r1, #4]
   0x400741dc <+12>:    str     r0, [r1, #4]
=> 0x400741e0 <+16>:    str     r0, [r2]
   0x400741e4 <+20>:    bx      lr
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) i r
r0             0x31220  201248
r1             0xbe9d1af0       3197967088
r2             0x46     70
r3             0x46     70
r4             0xbe9d1a98       3197967000
r5             0x40dd4c00       1088244736
r6             0x4136629f       1094083231
r7             0x1e400000       507510784
r8             0x41d720ab       1104617643
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x31d20  204064
r11            0xbe9d1944       3197966660
r12            0x30a58  199256
sp             0xbe9d1928       0xbe9d1928
lr             0x12df8  77304
pc             0x400741e0       0x400741e0 <std::_List_node_base::hook(std::_List_node_base*)+16>
cpsr           0x60000010       1610612752
(gdb)
```

code:

```
 //Type declaration
    struct SteadyNode { 
        double mean; 
        int duration; 
        int startLine; 
        time_t startDetectedRawTime; 
        time_t endDetectedRawTime; 
    }; 

//Definition info
//list<SteadyNode>::iterator upIt, downIt;
//list<SteadyNode> steadyNodeList;
//list<list<SteadyNode> > sleepPiceList;

{
    steadyNodeList.back().endDetectedRawTime = currentRawTime;
    SteadyNode last = steadyNodeList.back();
    if (onBedFlag == 1)
    {
        downIt = steadyNodeList.end();
        list<SteadyNode> onBedMeanList;
        onBedMeanList.splice(onBedMeanList.begin(), steadyNodeList, upIt, downIt);
        steadyNodeList.clear();
        steadyNodeList.push_back(last);

        sleepPiceList.push_back(onBedMeanList); //<=== crash position
        onBedMeanList.clear();
        onBedFlag = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        steadyNodeList.clear();
        steadyNodeList.push_back(last);
    }
}
```

**There is only one source code.
When I compiled successfully on the debian9 host, valgrind --leak-check=full tested no memory leaks and the program executed correctly.
On the arm platform, the compilation was successful, but the program got this error when it was executed. I hope to get everyone's help, thank you.**

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You most likely do something that leads to *undefined behavior*. When you build, do you get any warning messages? Have you enabled verbose warning messages (like `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`)? Are you doing any C-style casting to silence warnings (or even errors)?

Comment: `Cbox::SteadyNode` may have issues with allocation.  Valgrind will not catch portability errors like a 32bit overflow on a host using 64 bit integers; not that that is your issue, but you can hopefully see it as one of many possibilites.  People can only guess your issue with no clear answer and limited us to other future readers.  Can you please give more information on the cbox namespace/class and especially the allocation code.

Comment: Compile option -Wall is used. No any warnings

Comment: add some code segment, "//<=== crash position" mean SteadyAnalysis.h:237.

Comment: Please list your compiler options.  My guess if that you're using your development host's header files to cross-compile with.   Not a great move - it gives the illusion of working until it .... well...  crashes in importable places.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Those gdb print info is not major problem.

For gcc4.4 and gcc4.3, STL list will not pre alloc element when you write code like `list<DiyClass>`, but in gcc6.3 will. That is why the same code can run well in gcc6.3 but segment fault in gcc4.3.

I guess some low level implements is different between diff gcc version. if someone know detail reason, give a answer, thanks.